# near "varchar": syntax error

Tags: sqlite

```
01-16 21:50:06.898  29777-29777/com.example.administrator.simpleclock E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "varchar": syntax error
01-16 21:50:06.908  29777-29777/com.example.administrator.simpleclock W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d59438)
01-16 21:50:06.968  29777-29777/com.example.administrator.simpleclock E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "varchar": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table clock_list (mid INTEGER primary key ,meme varchar ,check  varchar ,hour integer,minute integer)
```

Comment: varchar(10) , will work

Comment: Check some of the others user's questions to see how to ask/structure your question.

Answer (score 2):

`check` is a keyword in SQL. Rename that column.